# mariadb declare variable syntax error

Tags: sql, mariadb, heidisql

Im using mariadb with heidisql to execute sql:

DECLARE @AccountID INT;

Insert Into accounts(first_name, mi, last_name, email, is_admin, is_enabled, date_created)
Values('testfirstname', 'a', 'testlastname', 'user@email.com', 1, 1, NOW());

set @AccountID = Last_Insert_Id();

I keep getting an error:

QL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@AccountID INT' at line 1 */

I was looking at the usage of Declare but it says that its used in a Function.  Ive tried with a BEGIN/END before the DECLARE and after with the same error.
I new to the mysql syntax where this would work in sql server.  so if anyone can let me know what i got wrong it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `DECLARE`. It is not neccessary.

Comment: why at their official website they still use "DECLARE" `https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/while/`

Comment: removing the DECLARE keyword doens't solve the problem at all for me.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using mariadb version 10.0.19

The above problem is described and has an easy solution
[here: Delimiters in the mysql Client](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/delimiters-in-the-mysql-client/)

in short:

**DELIMITER //**
create function .. as usual
BEGIN
.. as usual
END
**//

DELIMITER ;**

( The accepted solution did not worked ! )

Answer (score 1):

Just Ignore the DECLARE statement, and execute the Insert.

```
Insert Into accounts(first_name, mi, last_name, email, is_admin, is_enabled, date_created) Values('testfirstname', 'a', 'testlastname', 'user@email.com', 1, 1, NOW());

set @AccountID = Last_Insert_Id();
SELECT @AccountID;
```

Will get you the last inserted Id of the "accounts" table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I created my stored procedure in design

[image]
[image]

I wrote my stored procedure of function in `BEGIN` and `END`
and it worked